# Проблема с отображением полноразмерного фото по переданному пути в Android

Tags: android

Всем привет! Может кто - то сможет мне подсказать в чем моя ошибка. Логика такая - CaptureActivity делает фото, передает миниатюру и путь к файлу в адаптер, адаптер отображает миниатюру в GridView. По клику на айтем, у меня запускается DetailActivity в которую через intent я передаю путь к файлу. А уже в этой активити я должен по переданному пути отобразить полноразмерное изображение в imageView. Но, у меня ничего не отображается. В общем я уже запутался. Был бы очень благодарен если кто - нибудь взглянет на мой [проект](https://github.com/pochekutov/MyTestApp/tree/add_grid_layout/app/src/main/java/ru/pochekutov/mytestapp) и подскажет где у меня там косяк.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрел в код. В `CaptureActivity` передача параметра `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` закомментирована, связи между тем, что пришло в `onActivityResult` и `mPhotoURI` не будет.

Уже давно для камеры не писал, но помню что еще в `onActivityResult` надо дождаться окончания сканирования файла в медиа каталог, чтобы получить верный `Uri`.

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(...)
```